# how to get the full domain with http type (http or https) of a link in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net application will be distributed to different users. It should retrieve the domain and http type of a link automatically.

For example:

1. http://abc.com/test.aspx
2. https://abc.com/test2.aspx

I need a method to retrieve either: http://abc.com and https://abc.com from those links automatically.

How can I do that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a `Uri` from your full url and build your new url.

```
public string GetRootUrl(string url)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri(str);
   return string.Format("{0}://{1}", uri.Scheme, uri.Authority);
}
```

*However, you can use `uri.Host`, but in case of any deployment where you will host your application on a port like `http://abc.com:8087` then `uri.Host` will just return `abc.com` and `uri.Authority` will return `abc.com:8087`. Default port `80` will be ignored by `uri.Authority` and work like `uri.Host`.*

Answer (score 2):

```
string getSchemeAndHost(string str)
{
   var uri = new Uri(str);
   return uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host;
}
```